# An Error occurs when run "rakefile create:db" in Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I created an empty Ruby-on-rails project using PostgreSQL DB by this command.
**rails new my_app -T -d postgresql**
Then I ran this command to create DB.
**rake db:create**
Then An error occured like this:
Could not find gem 'pg (~> 1.1)' in rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/ or installed locally.
The source does not contain any versions of 'pg'
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
So, ran `bundle install` and It was also an error.
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.0.0/pg-1.2.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.0.0/pg-1.2.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
pg

Next,I ran **gem install pg -v '1.2.3'** command.
But this error occured.
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.0.0/pg-1.2.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.0.0/pg-1.2.3/gem_make.out

What is the reason?

Comment: Well, what does it say in the mkmf.log file?

Comment: What system are you working on ? (seems `pg` gem is not fully compatible with Ruby 3 in Windows : https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues/409 )

Comment: The content of mkmf.log file is below;                                                                        `"gcc -E -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <libpq-fe.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.`

Comment: I'm using windows 10 and Ruby-3.0.0 has been successfully installed.